# Using Windsor to automatically subscribe to event aggregator with custom facility

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, caliburn.micro

Reading [this](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2011/05/30/caliburn-micro-soup-to-nuts-part-8-the-eventaggregator.aspx) blog post it mentions you can get your DI container to automatically subscribe to events if it implements `IHandle<>`. That is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

Here is what I have so far.

```
container.Register(Component
    .For<MainWindowViewModel>()
    .ImplementedBy<MainWindowViewModel>()
    .LifeStyle.Transient
    .OnCreate((kernel, thisType) => kernel.Resolve<IEventAggregator>().Subscribe(thisType)));
```

While this code is successfully subscribing `MainWindowViewModel` to receive published messages, come time to actually receive messages nothing happens. If I manually subscribe all works as expected.

Here is my `MainWindowViewModel` class.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : IHandle<SomeMessage>
{
    private readonly FooViewModel _fooViewModel;
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public MainWindowViewModel(FooViewModel fooViewModel, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _fooViewModel = fooViewModel;
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        //_eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);

        _fooViewModel.InvokeEvent();
    }

    public void Handle(SomeMessage message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received message with text: {0}", message.Text);
    }
}
```

How can I tell Windsor to automatically subscribe if any class inherits `IHandle<>`?

I ended up coming up with this custom facility that subscribes.

```
public class EventAggregatorFacility : AbstractFacility
{
    protected override void Init()
    {
        Kernel.DependencyResolving += Kernel_DependencyResolving;
    }

    private void Kernel_DependencyResolving(ComponentModel client, DependencyModel model, object dependency)
    {
        if(typeof(IHandle).IsAssignableFrom(client.Implementation))
        {
            var aggregator = Kernel.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
            aggregator.Subscribe(client.Implementation);
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at the `EventAggregator` class provided by Caliburn.Micro I'm able to see that the subcription is successful, however if another class publishes a message the `MainWindowViewModel` class isn't getting getting handled. Manually subscribing still works but I'd like to automate this process. I have a feeling that it's not subscribing the correct instance. Not sure how to fix that, though.

I've also tried using every other event exposed by the `Kernel` property. Most of them can't resolve `IEventAggregator`.

What am I missing?

Comment: maybe you can convert this to windsor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871077/caliburn-micro-automatically-call-eventaggregator-subscribe-for-ihandle-implem

Comment: Very interesting link. Looks like I'll need a custom facility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I have a feeling that it's not subscribing the correct instance. Not
>   sure how to fix that, though."

You are subscribing to the type of the implementation (an instance of System.Type), not the actual dependency being resolved. The line:

```
aggregator.Subscribe(client.Implementation);
```

should be

```
aggregator.Subscribe(dependency);
```

Comment: Awesome. Not sure why I didn't check the type of `Implementation`. I'll award the bounty in an hour.

Comment: Glad I could help! Say if there's anything else :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to configure your IEventAggregator as a singleton. Not sure exactly how this would be done with Windsor, but with ninject you would do something like

```
Bind<IEventAggregator>().To<ConcreteEventAggregator>().InSingletonScope()
```

Having a singleton would ensure that all the events are aggregated into a single underlying dictionary (or the data type of your choice), instead of having a new one created every time you resolve IEventAggregator. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

this is how to impliment IHandler

```
public interface IHandle<TClass> : IHandle 
{  
    void Handle(TClass Subscriber);  
}
```

and this is how to use it..

```
    public class MyViewModel : IHandle<SubscriberType >
   {  
         public void Handle(SubscriberType Subscriber)
         {  
            //Do something here.
         }  
   }
```

Comment: As the example code I provided suggests I'm already doing this. I want a way to automatically subscribe if a type inherits from `IHandle<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be pretty late, but this is how i was able to acheive it

```
container.AddFacility<StartableFacility>();

container.Register(Component.For<ISubscriber<TagsProcessed>>()
                                    .ImplementedBy<TagsProcessedListener>()
                                    .OnCreate((kernel, instance) => eventAggregator.Subscribe(instance)).Start());
```